# Вывести все значения многомерного массива

Tags: php

Есть массив, в нем нам не известны ключи и уровень вложенностей (он может быть разным всегда).

Нужно получить все значения которые есть в этом массиве. То есть чтобы скрипт прошелся по всем ключам и уровням вложенности. Ключи могут быть как цифровые так и текстовые.

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: `array_walk_recursive()` в помощь

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение:

```
function array_values_recursive($ary) {
    $lst = array();
    foreach( array_keys($ary) as $k ) {
        $v = $ary[$k];
        if (is_scalar($v)) {
            $lst[] = $v;
        }elseif (is_array($v)) {
            $lst = array_merge($lst, array_values_recursive($v) );
        }
    }
    return $lst;
}
```

Источник: [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-values.php#41967)

Answer (score 0):

вывести все значения массива произвольной вложенности можно, используя `array_walk_recursive()`

```
array_walk_recursive($arr, function($v){  
          echo "$v\n";
     });
```

Если нужно их сложить в одномерный массив, то можно использовать эту же самую функцию

```
$result = [];
array_walk_recursive($arr, function($v) use (&$result){
           $result[] = $v;
     });
```